# IllegalArgumentException in createBitmap. Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to create a Bitmap, but, for some reason, this instruction in onDraw method throws a IllegalArgumentException

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(map,0,0,map.getWidth(),map.getHeigth(),matrix,true);
```

where map is correctly defined previously

```
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.map);
```

map.getWidth() and map.getHeigth() return 3072 (checked just before createBitmap(...))
And matrix:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(0.0625f, 0.0625f);`
```

The error is the following:

```
                             --------- beginning of crash
05-29 14:27:21.471 30685-31044/com.example.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2416
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 30685
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:829)
                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:739)
                at com.example.project.VistaMultitactil.onDraw(VistaMultitactil.java:236)
                at com.example.project.ThreadMultitactil.run(ThreadMultitactil.java:31)
```

I don't understand it because width and heigth are both of them 3072

Comment: HI this might be helpfull for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548155/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-in-android

Comment: the width of `map` must be bigger than the width of the resized bitmap

Comment: map.getWidth() returns 3072, so they are the same size. Should it be bigger or can it be equal?

Comment: It can be equal, i tried similar code and it worked for me. Make sure the width and height of `map` are not zero at the moment of reaching the `createBitmap`

Comment: Well, I don't know why that exception was thrown, but the problem is that i was creating the bitmap in onDraw method. I know it wasn't efficient but I didn't know that it was incorrect. If anyone can give a nice explanation to what happened, I'll take the answer as correct.